# Image is not get uploaded using php in ubuntu server on digitalocean?

Tags: php, image, ubuntu, upload, digital-ocean

The image is not get uploaded using PHP in ubuntu server on digitalocean even after changing permission to 777 and in the output of my code shows that image is uploaded? Previously it was showing that permission is not granted so I changed permission of this directory using `chmod 777 ./Images`.

```
<?php
    require_once '../config.php';
    require_once '../function2.php';

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST") {

        /*foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $params[$key] = $value;
        }*/

        $isImage = isset($_FILES['imgUrl']['tmp_name']);

        if ($isImage) {
            $upload_dir ="../Images/";
            echo "upload_dir: " . $upload_dir . "<br>";
            if (file_exists($upload_dir)) {
                if (is_writable($upload_dir)) {
                    $target = $upload_dir; //"dirname(__FILE__)" . "photos/";
                    $target = $target . 'Visnu.png';
                    $moved = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imgUrl']['name'], "$target");
                    echo "isMoved: " . $moved;
                } else {
                    echo 'Upload directory is not writable<br>';
                }
            } else {
                echo 'Upload directory does not exist.<br>';
            }
            echo $target . "<br>";
            //  echo dirname(__FILE__)."<br>";
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["imgUrl"]["name"] . "<br>";
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["imgUrl"]["type"] . "<br>";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["imgUrl"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
            echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["imgUrl"]["tmp_name"];
        }

        /*$url = $config['URLS']['API_PATH'] . $config['URLS']['ADD_USER_FORM'];

        echo $url;
        echo json_encode($params);

        $str = sendPostRequestWithImage($url, $params);

        echo "res: " . $str;

        $res = json_encode($str);

        if ($res['status']=='ok') {
            //header("location: ../signup-msg.php?success=0");
        }
        else {
            //header("location: ../signup-msg.php?success=1");
        }*/

    }
    else {
        header('location: ../404.php');
    }
?>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code you have:

```
$moved = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imgUrl']['name'], "$target");
```

the key must be `tmp_name` not `name`

`name` is the key for the original file on the user's pc.
`tmp_name` is the (tmp) name of the file on the server